# How to enter the value of EOF in the terminal

Tags: c

I have a C program.

```
int main ()
{
    if (getchar()!=EOF)
        puts("Got a character");
    else
        puts("EOF");
}
```

What should I type into the stdin on the terminal to produce an EOF?

Comment: try `putchar('%')` or `printf("%%")`

Comment: rather what should I give from keyboard to get control in else part ?

Comment: You never assign the character you read to `c`.

Comment: @user1593308, Have you tried pressing CTRL-D? Pl. check to see if this takes the code to the else part.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

In Windows, <kbd>Control+Z</kbd> is the typical keyboard shortcut to mean "end of file", in Linux and Unix it's typically <kbd>Control+D</kbd>.

Comment: Sir I want to print the integer value of EOF in C, how can I do this ?

Comment: the integer value of EOF in C is a value<0, so set your variable equal to getchar() and then print it out upon reading EOF

Comment: Unhelpfully, this is the first Google hit for "end of file keyboard shortcut".

Comment: @user1593308 Just do `printf("EOF=%d\n", EOF);`, no need to get the value from `getchar()`, just use the macro directly.

Answer (score 17):

1. EOF is wrapped in a macro for a reason - you never need to know the value.
2. From the command-line, when you are running your program you can send EOF to the program with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> (Unix) or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> (Microsoft).
3. To determine what the value of EOF is on your platform you can always just print it:

   ```
   printf ("%i\n", EOF);
   ```

Comment: `printf("%i", EOF)` prints `-1` instead of `Control+D`

Comment: @KMC - allow me to clarify.
Doing this:
    printf ("%i\n", 'K');
would print '75' and not 'K' after all. I also doubt if printing EOF as a character with "%c" will result in "CTRL+D" being printed. Depending on the terminal you might even get "?". 

Bear in mind that EOF is what the library returns when you *read* input, and is not representable as a printable character anyway. When you are *writing* output in your terminal, pressing CTRL+D (or whatever) causes the terminal to end input; it does not cause the terminal to generate a specific representation of EOF.

Hope this clears things up.

Comment: ubuntu 18. doesnt work. gives an error "bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"%i\n",'"

Comment: @Alex This isn't a bash question, so the answer is not a snippet of bash. It's a C question, hence the answer is a snippet of C code. IOW, type it into your C program, not your bash program.

Answer (score 7):

You can simulate an EOF with:

- Windows: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>
- Unix: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

It's not mentioned in any of the other answers so far, but you may need to press the right key combo (^D or ^Z) 2 or 3 times in order to actually signal EOF; [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959469/understanding-how-eof-and-ctrl-d-work) for explanation.