# Read strings from the standard input, concatenating what is read into one large string

Tags: c++

For some reason i cannot get for loop to work.
It doesn't print anything. Here is code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    string concatenated;
    for (string buffer; cin >> buffer; concatenated += buffer);
    cout << "The concatenated string is " << concatenated << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce. Do you actually input something and press enter?

Comment: Sorry I misspelled, it compiles. But after running it doesn't print anything.

Comment: Does it finish running or hangs?

Comment: you have ';' at the end of the for loop. your should remove it and will work fine

Comment: @ArkadyGodlin In this case it's supposed to be there.

Comment: @Sniper2Wolf It is working fin. [See here working](https://ideone.com/Fh7d2Z)

Comment: But perhaps it would be better form to actually have an empty block `{}` after the `for(...)` to telegraph what's going on?

Comment: I am working through the book c++ primer, and I need to do exercise which says
"Write a program to read strings from the standard input, concatenating what is read into one large string. Print the concatenated string."

Comment: i think you should add an exit string code, to break from the for loop. 
on visual studio 2015 except CTRL+C i was not able to exit this loop, and this keys throw exception.

Comment: @ArkadyGodlin Ok I have found the problem, I just needed to press CTRL+Z to exit the for loop.

Comment: Thank you guys for trying to help me.

Comment: @Sniper2Wolf it is not a full solution  you should add then try catch for your code or add an exit string so you can break from the loop
for example if (buffer == "exit") break;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `for-loop` will not exit automatically. It is continually go in loop and wait for next input. That's why you are not getting any outpur at your end.

You should enter <kbd>Control+Z</kbd> on Windows and <kbd>Control+D</kbd> on Unix plateforms to enter EOF character on . 
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968558/how-to-enter-the-value-of-eof-in-the-terminal) to know more.

The code is fine. [See it working here](https://ideone.com/Fh7d2Z)

Following is output from my local. The code used is same as posted and available [here](https://ideone.com/Fh7d2Z).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need something to stop the loop from waiting for more input.. You may use a special string to do this..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    string concatenated;
    for (string buffer; cin >> buffer && buffer!="STOP"; concatenated += buffer);
    cout << "The concatenated string is " << concatenated << endl;

    return 0;
}
```