# Why is there an extra "*" in the output of this program?

Tags: c, io, output, getchar, putchar

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () 
{ 
  int c; 
  while ((c = getchar ()) != EOF) 
    { 
      putchar (c); 
      printf ("*"); 
    }


  return 0; 
}
```

when I run this program, the output I get is as

```
qwerty                                          

q * w * e * r * t * y *
*
```

#I'm not getting how this last "*" is getting printed.

It has something to do with the return of `putchar()`. So how does `putchar()` function actually returns. I know that it returns after EOF is reached, so in that case, it won't print anything and `printf("*")` will get executed. But the thing is, why the last `*` is getting printed in the next line. Is it like `putchar()` returns and shift the printing pointer to new line?

One theory I get over this doubt is that, if I don't press 'enter' after giving input, `*` will not be printed. But it again created a question as of how do I get output (after giving the input), without pressing enter? And why is it like that the last `*` is there due to pressing 'enter'?

Answer (score 4):

When you give input "qwerty" and press enter key, the new line character `\n` appended to the input. So, the input to program would be:

```
"qwerty\n"
       ^^
```

When loop process the last (newline) character i.e. the `\n` character printed which actually moves the cursor to next line and the last star is getting printed after it.

To not to get the trailing new line character along with input, you can add check for new line character in `while` loop condition:

```
while ((c = getchar ()) != EOF && c != '\n')
```

Alternatively, you can give end of file `EOF` character instead of pressing enter key after entering input. For `EOF`, on Unix press <kbd>Control+D</kbd> and on Windows press <kbd>Control+Z</kbd>.

Comment: but when i declared variable, say n and initialized it with 0.
now, i'm replacing the extra condition you have given, with the condition 'n<10', and incrementing 'n' inside the while loop. then putchar() and the printf() statement inside while loop is not working. how it is so?

Comment: You would have to demonstrate that problem with a [mcve] as part of a new separate question. Please do not change this one away from the original question. There are already answers here, some of them upvoted.

Comment: @aambazinga I don't see any reason for which it wont work. It should work. Show the while loop condition.

Comment: @H.S. the reason is the same this construct "works" at all: line buffering on `stdin`. I assume he doesn't hit enter and expects some output appears after 10 characters. Won't happen.

Comment: @H.S. ctrl+d is working.. but the putchar is executing from the same line as on the input is given. ctrl+z is working differently.... (1)- it is not putting putting all characters, except the last *. (2)-it is skipping one line after the input and then * is printed.

Comment: @aambazinga On which OS you are compiling and running your program?

Comment: @H.S. its an online gdb compiler.

Comment: @aambazinga gdb is GNU debugger and not a compiler. I believe you mean to say gcc, which is a standard compiler for most Unix-like operating systems. On Unix you should use ctrl+d for EOF. The EOF is non printable ASCII character. Hence you will not see it in the terminal but as soon as you press ctrl+d, unlike enter key press which moves the cursor to next line, the program process the input and print output on the same line as on the input is given.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () 
{ 
  int c; 
  while ((c = getchar ()) != EOF) 
    { 
      putchar (c); 
      printf ("*"); 
    }
  return 0; 
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
QWERTY<Enter>

Enter also Taking as Character 
last '*' for <Enter> Character..
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will print one `*` for each other letter printed.
A newline is printed, note how the last `*` is alone in the last line.
The last `*` is for the `\n`, which is read when you enter the input with the return key.

You might want to stop the loop already at that newline, i.e.

```
while (((c = getchar ()) != EOF) && (c!='\n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

> how do I get output( after giving the input), without pressing enter?

You can press **Ctrl-D** after "qwerty" instead of pressing **Enter**.

Comment: Without further explanation, this should be a comment. Note that this also depends on the platform.

Comment: @FelixPalmen It is a partial answer, answering a part of the question which actually all the other partial answers did not answer. Isn't it?

Comment: @Yunnosch it could be, but then it's missing explanation. I'd be happy with it if it wasn't for the fact that Ctrl-D isn't a universal standard for giving EOF from the keyboard :o -- AFAIK, this already doesn't work on windows, Ctrl-Z should instead.

Comment: @FelixPalmen That is true. But it stays an answer, not a comment. Consider it a bad answer, with assumptions, but it is an answer.

Comment: @Yunnosch a matter of definition ... Yes, I wouldn't flag this NAA, but if it's an answer, it's partial **and** partially wrong and I'd say it's common practice to give this kind of little hints as comments instead.

Comment: @yahor zabalotski but i'm not getting that output in the next line. what if i want answer in the next line?

Comment: @aambazinga the approach is flawed anyways. What do you think why you can type a whole line before any output appears? Just because `stdin` is line buffered, something that can be disabled as well, then you'll get an asterisk as soon as you hit a single key. A sane approach here would be to read a whole line (e.g. with `fgets()`) and then iterate over the characters, outputting them with asterisks in between.

Comment: I made the OS assumption. Thanks for reminder me about it! Possibly,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968558/how-to-enter-the-value-of-eof-in-the-terminal answer clarified it.

Comment: @yahor zabalotski ctrl+D is for making the while loop false. i'm saying this because, after pressing ctrl+d, while loop condition becomes false and output is printed. but after that while loop is not taking any input(as int the case of enter, where we can iterate the loop for as per out need)

Comment: @aambazinga "*after pressing ctrl+d, while loop condition becomes false and output is printed.*" <- are you sure you know how `while` works? In your code, output is printed as long as the condition is **true**.

Comment: On Unix terminals `eof` can be changed from ctrl+d to something else using `stty` (you could make it ctrl+z on Unix if you reassign `susp` as well).  Confuses the heck out of people when you put it into a startup file like `.bashrc`.  So maybe the caveat: "ctrl+d by default".

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the site. H.S. has answered your main question. Nonetheless I wanted to add a little more explanation and address one of your other questions directly.

#### Terminal attributes

> But it again created a question as of how do I get output (after giving the input), without pressing enter?

The reason you need to press enter is that your terminal is in 'canonical' mode by default. From the UNIX manual for `tcsetattr`:

> In **canonical mode:**
>
> Input is made available line by line.  An input line is available when one of the line delimiters is typed (NL, EOL, EOL2; or EOF at the start of line).  Except in the case of  EOF,  the  line
>            delimiter is included in the buffer returned by read(2).

Note the fact that 'the line delimiter is included' also indirectly answers your question

> And why is it like that the last * is there due to pressing 'enter'?

(as pressing enter inserts the NL line delimiter - which the program just places in the input buffer along with the rest of the characters).

Depending on your platform, you may be able to *disable canonical mode*.

#### Disabling canonical mode

**NOTE:** The information below may be platform-specific. The `tcsetattr` functions *et. al* are part of the POSIX standard - but I don't know if they will work on Windows.

On Linux, for example, the following disables canonical mode and instructs the program to read input as soon as the user types a character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main(void) {
    char c = '\0';
    struct termios orig_attr, new_attr;

    tcgetattr(fileno(stdin), &orig_attr);
    memcpy(&new_attr, &orig_attr, sizeof(struct termios));
    new_attr.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);  // Disable canonical mode
    tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &new_attr);

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        printf("%c * ", c);
    }
    puts("");

    // Restore original terminal attributes
    tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &orig_attr);

    return 0;
}
```

**Notes:**

- The above code also disables terminal 'echo' (Otherwise you would see each of the characters printed twice).
- You may also want to set `new_attr.c_cc[VTIME]` and `new_attr.c_cc[VMIN]` for finer control of the read buffer. (See [man page](https://man.cx/tcsetattr) for details.)
- Ultimately - depending on your ultimate goal - maybe it is easier to just use `fgets` or `getline`?

Comment: it's really an interesting thing.. i've tried this out and the input is not getting buffered, direct output is getting printed.

Comment: i've one question here, so if we disable canonical mode, then context switching must be disabled in the processor..  because if it is not so, then some input must get lost due to lack of buffer.. am i right?

Comment: No. And not trying to disrespect this answer, but I'd suggest you stay within what C defines for now. Pulling OS-specific stuff in will only add to the confusion.

Comment: @aambazinga: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "context switching ... in the processor". Do you mean in the operating system _kernel_ (for switching processes)? If so, then no - you certainly don't need such radical measures. I can not think of a scenario where input might "get lost" (although perhaps other readers might know of one).

Comment: @aambazinga: This technique is not uncommon on Linux/UNIX operating systems. Nonetheless, if you need something that is operating system agnostic, maybe go with a simpler option such as `fgets` (as Felix Palmen suggested). In any case ... The above hopefully helps you to understand the issue at least.

Answer (score 0):

> It has something to do with the return of `putchar()`. So how does `putchar()` function actually returns. I know that it returns after EOF is reached, so in that case, it won't print anything and `printf("*")` will get executed.

This is very confused and you're completely on the wrong path here. `putchar()` just outputs a single character and returns as soon as this output is done. In fact, you could write the same code like this:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) 
{ 
   putchar(c); 
   putchar('*'); 
}
```

This means as long as `getchar()` is successful (no end of file), output the character you received and then immediately output an asterisk.

In fact, what you should expect to see when hitting the keys `qwerty` is something like this:

```
qq*ww*ee*rr*tt*yy*
```

This is assuming your terminal does "local echo", which means it shows anything you type.

The reason you don't see any output before hitting enter (or the platform-dependent control key for EOF, e.g. on *nix systems Ctrl-D) is simply that `stdin`, your input stream in C, is by default **line buffered**. This means that in your loop above, `getchar()` won't ever return unless you have a whole line of input or reach EOF.

As soon as `getchar()` returns, your loop will run. If you pressed enter, there will be a newline character in the input buffer and `getchar()` will read this as well, so it will also be output by the `putchar()` inside your loop, followed by an asterisk.

Note however that buffering modes can be changed ... if you disable buffering on `stdin`, you will probably see what I described above.

---

A sane way to implement what you want reliably is to read *a whole line* in your code and iterate over the characters you read. This could look for example like the following:

```
char buffer[1024];
if (fgets(buffer, 1024, stdin))
{
    for (char *c = buffer; *c; ++c)
    {
        putchar(*c);
        if (*c != '\n') putchar('*');
    }
}
```

With code like this, you have your own buffer and don't depend on the buffering mode of your input stream.

Comment: okay, so you are saying that whenever a new character is encountered, putchar() is called. if i get it right, then what is there to check for occurence of a character?

Comment: well, `getchar()`? As I said, your input stream is line buffered, so `getchar()` waits for input until a line is complete....