# A histogram of the length of words in its input. exercise 1_13, k&r pdf

Tags: arrays, c

I have just started learnign to program, and I'm having troubles writing a program from k&r second edition pdf, to write a a program histogram of the length of words in its input I imagined my program would be something like:

```
(words number)
  1     XXX
  2     XXXXX
  3     XX
  4
  5     X
        12345 (charcacters number)
```

Here is the code I have done so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define out 0
#define in 1

int main()
{
    char X, nc;
    int state, nw, i, x_count[10], c;

    i = 0;
    nc = 0;
    nw = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        x_count[i] = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (state == in && c != '\b' && c != ' ' && c != '\t')
            ++nc;
        else {
            ++nw;
            state = out;
        }

        if (state == out) {
            for (i = 0; i < nc; i++) {
                x_count[i] = X;
            }
        }

        state = in;
    }

    printf("%d: %c", nw, x_count[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One problem: `state == in` is undefined behaviour for at least the first loop as `state` is uninitialised.

Comment: If you need further help please describe your problem better than "having trouble". What trouble specifically?

Comment: @kaylum sorry for not being clear enough, when I run the program and type like 3 words and click enter, it doesnt show anything, just goes to the next line and waits for me to print something else again

Comment: It would help if you formatted your code to make it more readable. In particular, make indentation consistent and remove all that unnecessary whitespace. This may help for your described problem: [How to enter the value of EOF in the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968558/how-to-enter-the-value-of-eof-in-the-terminal)

Comment: Chihiro, when `x_count[i] = X;` is executed, what is the value of `X`?

Comment: Tip: enable all warnings to save time.

Comment: Monica, the program doesnt output aanything at all

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [@kaylum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3003365/kaylum) in the comment, the immediate problem that breaks the defined behavior of your code is your use of `state` before it has been assigned a value in:

```
    if (state == in && ...
```

`state` is a variable declared with *automatic storage duration*. Until the variable `state` is explicitly assigned a value, its value is *indeterminate*. Using `state` while its value is *indeterminate* results in *Undefined Behavior*. See: [C11 Standard - 6.7.9 Initialization(p10)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p10) and [J.2 Undefined Behavior](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2)

Once you invoke *Undefined Behavior* in your code, the defined execution is over and your program can do anything between appearing to run correctly or SegFault. See: [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/3422102)

The simple fix is to initialize `int state = out;` to begin with. (you will start in the `out` state in order to ignore leading whitespace before the first word)

You have similar problems with your variable `X` which is not initialized and is used when its value is indeterminate in `x_count[i] = X;` Moreover, it is unclear what you intend to do with `int X` to begin with. It is clear from your desired output:

```
(words number)
  1     XXX
  2     XXXXX
  3     XX
  4
  5     X
        12345 (charcacters number)
```

That you want to output one `'X'` per-character (to indicate the word length for your histogram), but there is no need to store anything in a variable `X` to do that, you simply need to output one character `'X'` for each character in the word. Additionally your output of `4` does not make much sense being empty as your state-variable `state` should prevent counting empty words. You would never have been `in` an empty word.

Compounding the confusion is your check for a backspace `'\b'` character when you check `EOF` and other whitespace characters for end of word. It looks more likely that you intended a `'\n'` but though an off-by-one-key typo you have `'\b'` instead of `'\n'`. That is conjecture that you will have to add details to clarify...

**A Word-Length Histogram**

K&R provides very good exercises and the use of a state-loop is a very good place to start. Rather than multiple-included loops to inch-worm over each word and skip over potentially multiple-included whitespace, you simply keep a state-variable `state` in  your case to track whether you are in a word reading characters, or before the first word, between words or after the last word reading whitespace. While you can simply the check for whitespace by including `ctype.h` and using the `isspace()` macro, a manual check of multiple whitespace characters is fine.

While defining `in` and `out` macros of `1/0` is fine, simply using a variable and assigning `0` for out or non-zero for in works as well. Since you are keeping a character-count to output a length number of `'X'` characters, you can just use your character count variable as your state-variable. It will be zero until you read the first character in a word, and then you would reset it to zero after outputting your length number of `'X'`s to prepare for the next word.

Initializing all variables, and reading either from the filename given as the first argument to the program, or from `stdin` by default if no argument is given, you can do something similar to:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    int cc = 0,     /* character count (length) */
        wc = 0;     /* word count */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    
    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    
    for (;;) {  /* loop continually */
        int c = fgetc(fp);                  /* read character from input stream */
        if (c == EOF || c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n') {   /* check EOF or ws */
            if (cc) {                       /* if characters counted */
                printf ("%3d : ", wc++);    /* output word count */
                while (cc--)                /* loop char count times */
                    putchar ('X');          /* output X */
                putchar ('\n');             /* output newline */
                cc = 0;                     /* reset char count */
            }
            if (c == EOF)                   /* if EOF -- bail */
                break;
        }
        else    /* otherwise, normal character */
            cc++;                           /* add to character count */
    }
    
    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
}
```

(**note:** the character-count `cc` variable is used as the state-variable above. You can use an additional variable like `state` if that is more clear to you, but think through way using `cc` above accomplishes the same thing. Also note the change and use of `'\n'` instead of `'\b'` as the literal *backspace* character is rarely encountered in normal input, though it can be generated -- while a `'\n'` is encountered every time the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed. If you actually want to check for teh *backspace* character, you can add it to the conditional)

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/histfile.txt
my dog has fleas
my alligator has none
```

**Example Use/Output**

Using a heredoc for input:

```
$ cat << eof | ./bin/wordlenhist
> my dog has fleas
> my alligator has none
> eof
  0 : XX
  1 : XXX
  2 : XXX
  3 : XXXXX
  4 : XX
  5 : XXXXXXXXX
  6 : XXX
  7 : XXXX
```

Redirecting from a file for input:

```
$ ./bin/wordlenhist < dat/histfile.txt
  0 : XX
  1 : XXX
  2 : XXX
  3 : XXXXX
  4 : XX
  5 : XXXXXXXXX
  6 : XXX
  7 : XXXX
```

Or passing the filename as a argument and opening and reading from the file within your program are all options:

```
$ ./bin/wordlenhist dat/histfile.txt
  0 : XX
  1 : XXX
  2 : XXX
  3 : XXXXX
  4 : XX
  5 : XXXXXXXXX
  6 : XXX
  7 : XXXX
```

Lastly, you can input directly on `stdin` and generate a manual `EOF` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> on Linux or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windows. (note: you will have to press the key combination twice -- can you figure out why?) E.g.

```
$ ./bin/wordlenhist
my dog has fleas my alligator has none  0 : XX
  1 : XXX
  2 : XXX
  3 : XXXXX
  4 : XX
  5 : XXXXXXXXX
  6 : XXX
  7 : XXXX
```

(also note where the first line of output is placed -- this will help you answer the last question)

If you would like to add a comment below and clarify your intent for `int X;` and `x_count[i] = X;` and the use of `'\b'` I'm happy to help further. Look things over and let me know if you have any questions.