# Which keyword will we use to exit EOF form c++ code?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, eof

I wrote c++ code in the codeblocks IDE. I use EOF but don't no which keyword i will use to exit form my code.
Here is my code:

```
int main() {
    int a, b;
    while ( scanf("%d%d",&a,&b)!=EOF) {
        printf ( "%d\n", a^b);
    } 
}
```

Comment: It depends on your system. I believe for windows it is Ctrl + Z

Comment: To close the stdin pipe in Linux, you need to Ctrl+D.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enter the value of EOF in the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968558/how-to-enter-the-value-of-eof-in-the-terminal), it's C duplicate but it works the same way.

Comment: The program is incorrect, it should check `== 2` rather than `!= EOF`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using windows   CTRL + C  is the code  for EOF()  as  Enter/Return key would add a newline only

Comment: yeap brother.
It's working for CTRL + C.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @mdshohed This isn't the right answer. Ctrl+C kills the whole program immediately, it doesn't make `scanf` return EOF. OP should be using Ctrl+Z, as the other answer suggests.

Answer (score 2):

The "scanf" return value is EOF for an error, or if the end-of-file character or the end-of-string character is found in the first attempt to read a character.

You can use "Ctrl + Z" in windows or "ctrl +D" for linux.